# cannot play the selected music after clicking the "ok" button of Mediastore

Tags: android

In this app, it can play the default music well, but when I try to use MediaStore to select another music to play, something wrong here. In the page of mediastore, it can play the selected music well, but when I click the "ok" button to confirm my choice, it cannot play the music anymore. I do not know why this happened and I am very glad to have your help!

The following is the code

```
public class MUSIC extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener  {
    private Button JoggingButton,BikingButton;
    private SensorManager mSensormanager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;
    private boolean initialization;
    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
    private static final String TAG = "sensor";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2;
    private double measurement;
    private double speed;
    private boolean jogging=false,biking=false;
    private Uri urijogging,uribiking;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private final static int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE=100;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST=9000;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music);

        mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();


        JoggingButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        BikingButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        if(accelerometer!=null){
            if(urijogging==null){
                Prepareplay(mediaPlayer1,Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+ "/raw/jogging1"));
            }else{
                Prepareplay(mediaPlayer1,urijogging);
            }
            if(uribiking==null){
                Prepareplay(mediaPlayer2,Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+ "/raw/biking1"));
            }else{
                Prepareplay(mediaPlayer2,uribiking);
            }
            mediaPlayer1.start();
            mediaPlayer2.start();

            JoggingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer1.release();
                    mediaPlayer1=new MediaPlayer();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                }
            });
            BikingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer2.release();
                    mediaPlayer2=new MediaPlayer();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 11);
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Current speed:"+String.valueOf(speed),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry,there are no accelerometers on your device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 10){
            urijogging=data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(urijogging),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Joggingplay(this,urijogging);
        }
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 11){
            uribiking=data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(uribiking),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Bikingplay(this,uribiking);
        }
    }
    private void Joggingplay(Context context, Uri uri) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer1.setDataSource(context, uri);
            mediaPlayer1.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer1.prepareAsync();
            onPrepared(mediaPlayer1);
            mediaPlayer1.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void Bikingplay(Context context, Uri uri) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer2.setDataSource(context, uri);
            mediaPlayer2.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer2.prepareAsync();
            onPrepared(mediaPlayer2);
            mediaPlayer2.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }


    public void Prepareplay(MediaPlayer player, Uri uri){
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the logcat

```
05-16 16:42:04.243 14390-14390/com.example.a12086.app_sensor E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
05-16 16:42:04.244 14390-14390/com.example.a12086.app_sensor E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
```

I searched this problem online, and I already used mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() and onPrepared(mediaPlayer), but it still do not work. And the selected music can only be played on the MediaStore page, I am confused about that...

Comment: why are you pausing in onPrepared after start?

Comment: Finally, i found it need to request permission to storage and only adding permission in Manifest is not enough. Hope it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

```
 try to Use:  mdiaPlayer.reset();
       mdiaPlayer.prepare();
       mdiaPlayer.start(); instead of 
       mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
       mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
       onPrepared(mediaPlayer);
       mediaPlayer.start();
```